# What does gapi_processed mean?

Tags: javascript, attributes

I've noticed the `gapi_processed` attribute on a lot of script tags lately but I can't find any good documentation on it.

What does it mean and where can I read more about it?

```
<script gapi_processed="true" src="..."></script>
```

**EDIT**
Here are a couple of examples (check the script tags in the `<head>` on the first two)

- http://www.myownbike.de/singlespeed-und-fixie-konfigurator
- https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs
- [Like buttons and like box vanished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746950/like-buttons-and-like-box-vanished/11747486#11747486) (The attribute is added in the answer, but why?)

It looks like it might have something to do with google?

Comment: "... on a lot of script tags"  - are there any examples?

Comment: Added a couple of examples

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

Answer (score 3):

If you load the Google Javascript client through creating a script tag:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js'
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

it loads the javascript, but it is not made available as a global on the window object immediately. "gapi_processed" is set to true when window.gapi is a populated object.

for script tags originating in the HTML markup, if you view source through chrome developer tools, you will notice that the attribute is highlighted as changed.